# Finding solutions using Gauß-Jordan-Algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I have matrix A = 
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3&4&5\\2&4&3&5&4\\3&6&5&8&7\end{bmatrix}

and\vec b = \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}

I expanded the matrix by adding the elements of the vector to the matrix.
At first I changed the form of the matrix to get a reduced form.

1.R2 - 2xR1

2.R3 - 3xR1

3.R1 + R2

4.R2-R3

5.R3 + 4x R2

Performing these operations, I have the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&1&-1&1\\0&0&1&1&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
Now I need to remove the last row because it contains only zeros. After that I need to expand the matrix to a n x n+1 matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&1&-1&1\\0&0&1&1&2&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
At this point, I'm rather confused, because it says, that some zeros need to be replaced by a -1 but I don't know which one.

Comment: You can choose $x_1$ , $x_4$ and $x_5$ arbitary. Then $x_2$ and $x_3$ are determined by the choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
\begin{align*}
A &=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
2 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 4 \\
3 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7
\end{array}\right] &
\vec b &= \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

You have correctly shown that $\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}$
$$
\rref
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 \\
2 & 4 & 3 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\
3 & 6 & 5 & 8 & 7 & 3
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{rrrrr|r}
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right]
$$
This tells us that $A\vec x=\vec b$ if and only if 
$$
\begin{array}{rcrcrcrcrcrcrcrc}
x_1 &+& 2\,x_2&+&0\,x_3&+&x_4&+&(-1)\,x_5&=& 1 \\
0\,x_1 &+& 0\,\,x_2&+&x_3&+&x_4&+&2\,x_5&=& 0 
\end{array}
$$
That is, $A\vec x=\vec b$ if and only if
$$
\vec x=
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1-2\,x_2-x_4+x_5\\
x_2\\
-x_4-2\,x_5\\
x_4\\
x_5
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}
+x_2\begin{bmatrix}
-2\\1\\0\\0\\0
\end{bmatrix}+
x_4
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\0\\-1\\1\\0
\end{bmatrix}+
x_5
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\0\\-2\\0\\1
\end{bmatrix}
$$